# Groovy + Spock testing void method of type "Validator" that throws error when conditions are not met

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I use Groovy + Spock as unit testing tool and I wonder how to write testing methods that return void - sth like validator that can throw an error when conditions are not fulfilled. WHat with then clause?

```
def "should pass without errors when..."() {
        given:
        //preparing data

        when:
        validator.validate(preparedObject) /// of type void, throws error when conditions not met

        then:
        ???????????????
    }
```

What's the best practice for tha situation:

```
then:
true
```

???

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
then:
noExceptionThrown()
```